# How does networkmanager (nmcli) able to get my wifi signal strength without root privilege?

Tags: linux, wifi, networkmanager, strace

On my system, to find out the quality of the connected wifi signal I'd have to run `sudo iwconfig wlp6s0` where `wlp6s0` is the name of the device interface I'm using to connect to the wifi. The output doesn't show the link quality or signal level if I don't run the command with `sudo`. However, I can get the signal strength of the wifi using `nmcli` without using `sudo` e.g. `nmcli dev wifi`.

Running `sudo strace iwconfig wlp6s0`, I had found that it uses `ioctl` system call as indicated in a line the `strace` output:

`ioctl(3, SIOCGIWSTATS, 0x7ffd1bd7e960)  = 0`

But it turns out `strace nmcli dev wifi` doesn't use the same system call to obtain the wifi signal strength or relevant informations.

I want to know how `nmcli` obtain the information it need to be able to show the wifi signal strength without using `sudo`.

EDIT: Output of both `strace`s:

1. Full output of `strace nmcli dev wifi`: https://pastebin.com/NdqBfC8W
2. Full output of `sudo strace iwconfig wlp6s0`: https://pastebin.com/5w0Grwze

Answer (score 1):

It likely contacts the Network Manager service using D-Bus, and the Network Manager service runs as root.

```
~ ps -o pid,user,cmd -C NetworkManager
  PID USER     CMD
  894 root     /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
```

Comment: Thank you, my life make sense now. This seems to be the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm **not** running network manager, and `/sbin/iw wlan0 station dump` can show the signal strength just fine without being root.

If I do an `strace`, I see it creates a NETLINK socket and seems to get the data from this socket. For more details, I suppose one should read the source of `iw`.

Comment: It doesn't output anything for me, with or without being root.